# How to display WCF HTTP codes in service response

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, wcf, rest

I'm working through a web service using WCF and Entity Framework and I would like to know how to view or return HTTP status codes to the calling clients.

The code I have is as follows:

IUserService.cs

```
   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "/GetUsers")]
        List<User> GetUsers();
```

UserService.svc.cs

```
  public List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            var userController = new UserController();
            return userController.GetUsers();
        }
```

UserController.cs

```
 public List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            List<User> serverResponse = new List<User>();

            try
            {
                using (var db = new MyEntities())
                {
                  List<user> userList = db.users.ToList();

                    foreach (user userRecord in userList)
                    {
                        User userDto = new User();
                        userDto.userId = userRecord.user_id;
                        userDto.name = userRecord.user_name;
                        serverResponse.Add(userDto);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return serverResponse;
```

USER DTO

```
  [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "userId")]
        public int userId { get; set; }

    }
```

I've seen when using or working on other APIs that the status code can be returned in a dictionary like response, for example "success" "200" in a key value pair in the client calling response. Is there a way to enable something like this for WCF in the web.Config or the Interface class? I'd like the client to be able to receive error codes for success or failure to be able to react if something goes wrong. When I run this request in the browser I get back the following valid JSON:

```
 [
    {
        "name": "APIClientTestUser",
        "userId": 212,
    }
]
```

Either with this JSON or somewhere else I would like the client to know that the call succeeded or failed with the appropriate HTTP code. Any tips or advice on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most simple approach would be to wrap your results into generic response objects

```
[DataContract]
public class Response<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public T Result { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

// then your declaration
Response<List<User>> serverResponse = Response<List<User>>();

// on success
serverResponse.Result = userList;
serverResponse.Status = 200; // ok

// on fail
serverResponse.Status = 500; // fail

// and contract
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "/GetUsers")]
Response<List<User>> GetUsers();
```